# ISNULL or any alternative in sql server when not data present for subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a situation, Where I need to get some data in case I find no data for certain query. e.g.

```
select id from abc where userid='XYZ'
```

In this case I will get the Id, only if the record with userid='XYZ' is present in the table abc.

Below given code will give 123 only if id is present as null .This is not what I'm expecting.

```
select isnull(id,123) from abc where userid='XYZ'
```

I want something like:
*If no data in abc with userid='XYZ', then some specific value should be output.* 
e.g.

```
select isnull((select id from abc where userid='XYZ'),123)
```

Is there any similar shortcut for the above query?? Please suggest. Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming that at most one row matches (as implied by your third query) then `SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id),123) FROM abc WHERE userid='XYZ'`. Possible duplicate of [How to return default value from SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503463/how-to-return-default-value-from-sql-query)

Comment: @MartinSmith : It works fine.! What if, "id" column is nullable ?

Comment: @pavan6e - Then it would behave the same way as your third query. It won't return `NULL`. For that you could do `SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 123 ELSE MAX(id) END FROM abc WHERE userid='XYZ'`

Comment: @MartinSmith I think you need to make your comment an answer!

Comment: Shouldn't the SQL function be IFNULL instead of ISNULL ?

Answer (score 1):

isnull work on the "column" level, what you need is if a row is null, then print something else.

I would UNION ALL your select with a "dummy" select containing only one row with the data you want to be displayed in case nothing returns, then select top 1 from that with a order. Like

```
select top 1 id
from (
    select id, 1 from abc where userid='XYZ'
    UNION ALL
    select 123, 0
) X
order by 1 DESC
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the `TOP 1`. Also looks essentially the same as podiluska's except with `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. Whilst that is preferable not sure it warranted a new answer rather than a comment.

Comment: yes I forgot the top 1. Regarding UNIONS, always use UNION ALL when possible because UNION has to go trough the process on eliminating the duplicates, which has a cost (not in this case of course because there are 2 rows only but I always use it for good practice)

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 id
from
(
      select 1 as id, value from abc where userid='xyz'
      union 
      select 2, 123 
) v
order by ranking
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable if the result is only going to return one row.

```
DECLARE @Id INT;

SELECT @Id = id FROM abc WHERE userid='XYZ';

SET @Id = ISNULL(@Id, 123);

SELECT @Id AS Id;
```

Comment: And for multiple records?

Comment: @Schalk - For multiple records a variant on podiluska's answer could be used. It would need `TOP 1 WITH TIES` and `UNION ALL`.