# MySQL - SELECT IN clause with non matching elements in output?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT name, age
FROM mytable
WHERE name IN ("Bob", "Rob", "Robert");
```

will list me only those rows with names "Bob", "Rob", "Robert".

Is is possible to obtain a an output like the following using (My)SQL only?

```
Bob, 23
Rob, NULL (meaning there is no Rob in the table)
Robert, 30
```

instead of the usual:

```
Bob, 23
Robert, 30
```

Comment: Maybe like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503463/how-to-return-default-value-from-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Try following code that uses union for missing names:

```
select * from mytable WHERE name IN ("Bob", "Rob", "Robert")
union
select "Bob", null from mytable where not exists (SELECT Name FROM Person where name in ("Bob"))
union
select "Rob", null from mytable where not exists (SELECT Name FROM Person where name in ("Rob"))
union
select "Rober", null from mytable where not exists (SELECT Name FROM Person where name in ("Robert"));
```